# How to Create or configure Rest Template using @Bean in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I want to define `RestTemplate` as an application bean using `@Bean` annotation in my configuration class in a spring boot application.

I am calling 4 rest services in different places in my application flow. Currently I am creating `RestTemplate` every time every request. Is there a way I can define that as application bean using `@Bean` and inject that using `@Autowired`?

Main reason for this question is I can able to define `RestTemplate` using `@Bean` but when I inject it with `@Autowired` I am loosing all defined interceptors (Interceptors are not getting called.)

**Configuration Class**

```
@Bean(name = "appRestClient")
public RestTemplate getRestClient() {

    RestTemplate  restClient = new RestTemplate(
        new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()));

    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
    interceptors.add(new RestServiceLoggingInterceptor());
    restClient.setInterceptors(interceptors);

    return restClient;
}
```

**Service Class**

```
public class MyServiceClass {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate appRestClient;

    public String callRestService() {
        // create uri, method response objects
        String restResp = appRestClient.getForObject(uri, method, response);
        // do something with the restResp
        // return String
    }
}
```

It seems my `Interceptors` are not getting called at all with this configuration. But `RestTemplate` is able to make a call to the REST service and get a response.

Comment: Are you sure you're injecting the same `RestTemplate` instance, you might be picking up some other bean? Try adding `@Qualifier("appRestClient")` from `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier` next to your `@Autowired` annotation.

Comment: thanks for your input daniel.When I tried with @Qualifier Interceptors are not getting picked up.I guess I am missing something here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Judging form the name of the interceptor, I'm guessing you're doing some logging in it? You could of missed **logging level configuration**. I created a small application to check weather your configuration works, using `1.3.6.RELEASE` version.

In this class I define the `RestTemplate` bean and the interceptor with logging.

```
package com.example;

// imports...

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "appRestClient")
    public RestTemplate getRestClient() {
        RestTemplate restClient = new RestTemplate(
                new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()));

        // Add one interceptor like in your example, except using anonymous class.
        restClient.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList((request, body, execution) -> {

            LOGGER.debug("Intercepting...");
            return execution.execute(request, body);
        }));

        return restClient;
    }
}
```

For logging to work, I also have to set the correct debug level in `application.properties`.

```
logging.level.com.example=DEBUG
```

Then I create a service where I inject this `RestTemplate`.

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    private final RestTemplate appRestClient;

    @Autowired
    public SomeService(@Qualifier("appRestClient") RestTemplate appRestClient) {
        this.appRestClient = appRestClient;
    }

    public String callRestService() {
        return appRestClient.getForObject("http://localhost:8080", String.class);
    }
}
```

And also an endpoint to test this out.

```
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    private final SomeService service;

    @Autowired
    public SomeController(SomeService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testEndpoint() {
        return "hello!";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test() {
        return service.callRestService();
    }
}
```

By performing a `GET` request to `http://localhost:8080/test` I should expect to get the String `hello!` getting printed (the service makes a call to `http://localhost:8080` which returns `hello!` and sends this back to me). The interceptor with logger also prints out `Intercepting...` in the console.

Answer (score 10):

Answer for **Spring boot 2.*.* version**.

I am using **Spring boot 2.1.2.RELEASE** and I also added **RestTemplate** in my project in a class where mail method exists.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {

    return builder.setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(300000))
     .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(300000)).build();
}
```

and Used in my **service or other classes** like this

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate res;
```

and **in methods**

```
 HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(str, headers);
            return res.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Object.class);
```

Answer (score 5):

Edd's solution won't work if you're using Spring Boot 1.4.0 or later. You will have to use RestTemplateBuilder to get this working. Here is the example

```
@Bean(name="simpleRestTemplate")
@Primary
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder){

    RestTemplate template = restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()))
                                                .interceptors(logRestRequestInterceptor) //This is your custom interceptor bean
                                                .messageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter())
                                                .build();
    return template;


}
```

Now you can autowire the bean into your service class

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("simpleRestTemplate")
private RestTemplate simpleRestTemplate;
```

Hope this helps